# Is it possible to run remote calls to two different methods in the same thread in Java RMI?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, rmi

Suppose that Remote `class RemoteServer` has two remote methods `method1` and `method2`.

Is it possible to run the remote calls to these two methods *in the same thread* of the server in Java RMI?

It is known that `method1` will be called first.

---

I have read ["Thread Usage in Remote Method Invocations" (below)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/rmi/spec/rmi-arch3.html) and have no ideas.

> A method dispatched by the RMI runtime to a remote object implementation may or may not execute in a separate thread. The RMI runtime makes no guarantees with respect to mapping remote object invocations to threads.

Comment: The answer based on that quote is a firm no.

Comment: Why do you think you need them to run in the same thread?

Comment: @Kayaman In `method1`, I use a `writeLock.lock()` and I want to unlock it using `writeLock.unlock()` in `method2`. Here, `writeLock` is an `ReentrantReadWriteLock`.

Comment: @hengxin Sounds like you've got a design issue. Fix your remote method so that you don't need to unlock the lock in a different method.

Comment: @Kayaman I am implementing a two-phase distributed protocol (actually, the [2PC protocol (wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-phase_commit_protocol)) which involves a coordinator and multiple participants. In the first phase, the coordinator invokes `method1` of all participants which need to lock some resources. After doing something else, the coordinator invokes `method2` of all participants which need to unlock those resources. How should I use lock mechanisms in this scenario?

Comment: How did you come up with the idea to do 2 phase commit with RMI?

Comment: Don't forget to write code to handle the case where the client goes away after making the first call, and never makes the second call.

Comment: @Kayaman I used RMI first. Later I found that a 2PC protocol is needed.

Comment: You need to have `method1()` return something that can be passed by `method2()` to identify the transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though your question indicates that there's a good chance you can find better program design, if you really need such functionality, you can implement it by means of `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a single thread. Just wrap your methods `method1()` and `method2()` into two different `Callable`'s and submit them to your single-threaded pool.

```
class Method1Task implements Callable<Void> {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        // method 1 body here
        return null;
    }
}

class Method2Task implements Callable<Void> {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        // method 2 body here
        return null;
    }
}

...

// Create a single-thread pool and use it to submit tasks
private final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

void method1() {
    executor.submit(new Method1Task());
}

void method2() {
    executor.submit(new Method2Task());
}
```

If you need to wait for method completions, use `Future`s that are returned by `submit()`s. If you need to return values from the methods, change `Void` for appropriate data types.

In Java 8 it's simpler, you don't need the `Callable`s:

```
executor.submit(() -> {
    // call the method you need here
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it will work. However, this method will prevent any possible concurrency among all remote calls to `method1` and `method2`. What I actually want is to "run the remote call to `method2` with the same thread for `method1` whenever *the caller to them is the same*". (It is easy to distinguish the callers and it is known that `method1` is called first.) Is it possible to generalize your code to cover this fine-grained case?

Comment: In such case you need to have several `ExecutorService`s, one for every caller. When a call arrives, you retrieve the corresponding executor (from a map, for instance) and use it to submit the task. But be careful, `ExecutorService` is relatively expensive to instantiate, so it's better to have a pool of them rather than create them for every new transaction and destroy after the transaction is finished.